# ASP.NET with SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql

How do I display, edit and save an Excel sheet data in sql server?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB](http://ssis.wik.is/Data_Sources/Microsoft_Office_(2007)) provider to connect to an Excel sheet using an OLEDB connection. You can then [query the Excel sheet directly](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/Excel_data_access.aspx) like you would do a database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this connection string for excel 2003:

```
con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
                filePath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0");
```

and for Excel 2007, you can use this connection string:

```
con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                filePath + ";Excel 12.0;HDR=YES");
```

After if you can execute direct query for excel sheet.
You can also take the reference of "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll" DLL and use it.